# XSL loop with counter?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xML, which has lots of elements, some looks like that:

```
<Images>
−
<Image>
<FileName>L_03AB1B13144B416A8E779E0010D27156_iList.jpg</FileName>
<SequenceNumber>8</SequenceNumber>
<IsDefault>False</IsDefault>
</Image>
−
<Image>
<FileName>L_36438628E6E343919D77A3D27877A650_iList.jpg</FileName>
<SequenceNumber>9</SequenceNumber>
<IsDefault>False</IsDefault>
</Image>
−
<Image>
<FileName>L_3E0BFE975FA04A46848C3B3D983C4DE7_iList.jpg</FileName>
<SequenceNumber>10</SequenceNumber>
<IsDefault>False</IsDefault>
</Image>
−
<Image>
<FileName>L_DAD3FA64670E40F5BD0B48343216BF76_iList.jpg</FileName>
<SequenceNumber>11</SequenceNumber>
<IsDefault>False</IsDefault>
</Image>
−
<Image>
<FileName>L_2522D5E120574582A926032E1DF4733F_iList.jpg</FileName>
<SequenceNumber>12</SequenceNumber>
<IsDefault>False</IsDefault>
</Image>
</Images>
```

I would like to loop on every filename, which is easy with for-each, but I want to count it,and produce something like that (XML):

```
<pic_1>L_03AB1B13144B416A8E779E0010D27156_iList.jpg</pic_1>

<pic_2>L_36438628E6E343919D77A3D27877A650_iList.jpg</pic_2>
```

etc... (take a look at the elements, 1,2...)
how do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to name equal elements differently. Instead of `<pic_1>, <pic_2>` do `<pic num="1">, <pic num="2">`.

This makes your life *a lot* easier when working with the XML document later. XPath queries, XSLT transformations, DOM operations - anything will be much simpler and much more consistent.

```
<xsl:template match="Image">
  <pic num="{position()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="FileName" />
  </pic>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the "xsl:element" tag:

```
<xsl:element name="pic_{position()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="FileName" />
</xsl:element>
```